# Fallback to CButton default drawing in Owner Draw mode

Tags: mfc

The context is that i implement a OwnerDraw button, but there is a case my data for drawing is not avaiable. In such a case, I need to fall back to default Window button. Is there anyway I can call default window button's drawing function from DrawItem() of a owner-draw enabled button?

LRs

Comment: Why not just change the button style back to a non owner-drawn button?

Answer (score 0):

You may start with [DrawFrameControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)